# Ruby Variables (Extern?)

Tags: ruby

I've just started programming in Ruby and i'm trying to work on a little debug switch that works similar as to below, similar to a C extern variable. My problem is, Im not sure how to have a variable in one file in module X of one file, and access it in the same module of another file.

I'd prefer to not use global variables as they are not limited by scope - is there a scope wide variable I can do this with?

(note, this is std ruby 2.0.0 - NOT rails!)

Cheers,
Chris

---

```
#file A.rb
module foo
@@myVariable = 'ruby'
   ##do something
end #end foo

#file B.rb
module foo
   module self.bar(x)
        if(@@myVariable == 'ruby')
           puts 'do a barrel roll'
        end
   end #end bar
   ##do something
end #end foo
```

---

```
undefined variable @@myVariable
```

Comment: Your example shows a class variable, not a global variable.

Comment: `module foo` should be a syntax error. module names must be constant (unless you create an anonymous module)

Comment: You should look at module/class constants in Ruby, and also "instance" variables on the class or module itself.

Comment: Apologies, the example I knocked together very quickly and didn't bother checking - I used a class variable as this is the most similar thing I could to the required scope that I could find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for file A to affect the code in file B, B needs to `require` A.

A.rb

```
module Foo
  @@x = 1
end
```

B.rb

```
require './A'

module Foo
  def self.bar
    @@x
  end
end

p Foo.bar
# 1
```

Comment: Note that you have put the variable in the same module, while it _looks_ like the OP wanted to have a namespaced sub-module `Foo::Bar` checking for a value on `Foo`.

Comment: Essentially yes - I was attempting to use `Foo` as a namespace wrapper for both files

Comment: @Phrogz oh jeez, I didn't notice that. There's so much wrong with OP's code it's hard to point out exactly what needs fixing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# file_a.rb
module Foo
  BARREL_ROLL = true
end



# file_b.rb
require_relative 'file_a'

module Bar
  if Foo::BARREL_ROLL == true
    puts 'do a barrel roll'
  end
end
```

**Notes**:

1. `@@myVariable` is a `class variable` and typically not recommended to use, try to refrain from using it.
2. I understand you are just starting out Ruby, perhaps checking out the [style guide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby) may help you improve to a more `Rubyesque` way of doing things; your code seems to be influenced by your previous language's style. Following the guide will make your code more readable for most in the community and soon for yourself.